# what are the attributes(?) of user.username?

Tags: django

Where can I find the documentation on the attributes(is that what it's called?) of the user model fields?

I'm using the `UserPassesTestMixin`, and I want to include 3 different usernames to pass the test.

I'm also doing a `{% if user.username %}` code in the HTML that includes the same 3 usernames.

But I don't know how to do it.

```
class StaffAutho(UserPassesTestMixin):
     def test_func(self):
         return self.request.user.username.includes('staff1', 'staff2', 'staff3')
```

This is the html:

```
{% if user.username == 'tim' %}
   <li class="nav-item pl-3">
     <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="/productadmin">Admin</a>
   </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `username in <list>`

Comment: It might be better to use `self.request.user.is_staff` rather than checking the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.username` is just a string. That means you can use the regular Python `in` operator to check whether the username is present in a list or tuple of usernames:

```
class StaffAutho(UserPassesTestMixin):
     def test_func(self):
         return self.request.user.username in ('staff1', 'staff2', 'staff3')
```

Django templates also [support the use of the `in` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator). You could pass the list of usernames to the template from the view:

```
render(request, 'my_template.html', {'staff_users': ['staff1', 'staff2', 'staff3']})
```

And then in the template check whether the current user is in that list:

```
{% if user.username in staff_users %}
   <li class="nav-item pl-3">
     <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="/productadmin">Admin</a>
   </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! However is there a document that list these "operators" for the string? eg. user.username.startswith/contains/endswith. I believe they're not the standard python operators

Comment: @PaulZet `startswith`, `contains`, `endswith` are methods on Python's `string` type. There's a complete list of them in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: Thank you! I'm assuming when I'm using these methods for models, the method has to return a True or False?